# How to make a character pursue the player's character in a JS / canvas game?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm just starting to code a simple JS game using canvas, but i don't have any ideas of how the main mechanic would work: it's an endless game, where the player must run from the monster and enter a door before the monster reaches him.

So, i have the canvas and the player moving, but i still didn't started the monster mechanics. I think that would be to update every monster's frame with the x/y player's position, right?

Code that i wrote so far:

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 600;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

const survivor = {
    x: 25,
    y: 25,
    moveUp:    function() { this.y -= 25 },
    moveDown:  function() { this.y += 25 },
    moveLeft:  function() { this.x -= 25 },
    moveRight: function() { this.x += 25 },
  }

  function draw(survivor) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => { 
       ctx.drawImage(img, survivor.x, survivor.y, 50, 50); 
    }
    img.src = "/images/survivor-move_knife_0.png";
  }




  document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 38: 
        survivor.moveUp();    
        console.log('up: ', survivor); 
        break;
      case 40: 
        survivor.moveDown();  
        console.log('down: ',  survivor); 
        break;
      case 37: 
        survivor.moveLeft();  
        console.log('left: ',  survivor); 
        break;
      case 39: 
        survivor.moveRight(); 
        console.log('right: ', survivor); 
        break;
    }
    updateCanvas();
  })

  function updateCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,1500,1700);


    draw(survivor);
  }



  updateCanvas()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

Given the code you posted, a simple (but not very efficient) way would be to use setInterval() to run your monster's logic.

A very simple logic could work like this (pseudo code):

```
if ( monster.canMoveLeft() && player.x < monster.x ) {
    monster.moveLeft()
} else if ( monster.canMoveRight() && player.x > monster.x ) {
    monster.moveRight()
} else if ( monster.canMoveUp() && player.y < monster.y ) {
    monster.moveUp()
} else if ( monster.canMoveDown() && player.y > monster.y ) {
    monster.moveDown()
} else {
    // no good choice
    // either continue moving in the same direction, or choose a random
    // direction if that's not possible
    //
    // This means you need to keep track of the monster's last direction
}
```

You could also check the distance on the horizontal and vertical axis to determine which direction to go first.

- List item

Comment: Glad I could help. It would be appreciated, if you could accept my answer (by clicking thee checkmark next to it), so this question is marked resolved. :)

What kind of game are you coding? I guess some sort of maze game?